# How do I tell if my Godox trigger or flash needs a firmware update?

Tags: firmware, godox

I'm having an issue with my Godox gear, and I often see people referring to updating the Godox firmware. But I'm not sure how to tell if my Godox gear needs to be updated to fix my issue.  How do I find out?

Comment: If it is anything like Yongnuo, and if it is working at all at any basic level, the answer is, "If it ain't broke, don't fix it!" On a more serious note, good info in both of these questions/answers.

Comment: Will there be a third installment regarding "How do I insure that the Godex/Flashpoint gear I purchase already has the latest firmware installed?

Comment: @MichaelClark, Why would you need to buy insurance for that? :)  I _am_ trying to figure out an on-topic way to do the "how do I update yongnuo/godox firmware on a mac?" question but haven't yet contrived it so it won't be closed or migrated to Ask Different, where they'll just tell you to use WineBottler, which won't work (non-standard USB driver). My brain feels fuzzy. I may have to take it to meta or just drop the idea.

Comment: @MichaelClark, you wanna handle the "can't trigger my Godox flash" x/y question where y is not distinguishing optical slave mode from radio slave mode?

Comment: I need insurance because there is no way to ensure that I'll get the most up-to-date firmware.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are three steps to determine this.

1. Find out what firmware version you're currently using:

   - **Devices with a MENU button** (other than the AD200/AD200 Pro), press the **MENU** button.
   - **A1**: Hold down the **SET** button while turning on the trigger.
   - **AD200**: Hold down the **MODE** button while turning on the strobe.
   - **AD360 II**: Hold the **Zm/C.Fn** button to enter the custom function menu.
   - **TT350 / V350**: Hold down the **MODE** button while turning on the flash.
   - **TT685 / TT685 II / V860 II / V860 III**: Hold the **Zm/C.Fn** button to enter the custom function menu.
   - **X1T** transmitter: Hold down the **MODE** button while turning on the trigger.
   - **X1R** receiver: Hold down the **GR** button while turning on the unit.
2. Find out what the latest version of the firmware for your device is and what it does, by going to [the Godox firmware webpage](https://www.godox.com/firmware-flash/). The Godox page lists the current version of each firmware image, its release date, and (kinda) describe what it does. If you're interested in what earlier versions do, you must download the .rar archive of the firmware download, and extract the PDF file inside, which has the entire version history in both Chinese and English.
3. Decide for yourself if you need the update or not. This may hinge on how you interpret the sometimes cryptic (translated) descriptions of the functionality that was fixed or added in the Godox documentation.  So, doing a bit of research on messageboards for reports of whether the firmware update does what you think it does may also be in order.

See also:

- [How do I troubleshoot my Godox firmware updating process?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/98901/how-do-i-troubleshoot-my-godox-firmware-updating-process?rq=1)
- [How can I update the firmware on my Godox gear on a Mac (OSX) or Linux computer?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/106262/how-can-i-update-the-firmware-on-my-godox-gear-on-a-mac-osx-or-linux-computer?rq=1)

Comment: I *knew* I had to hold down a button while turning it on, but couldn't figure out *which* one.

Comment: @xiota, why do you think I wrote this puppy!? :D  _I_ needed some way to look it up!