# Can't make Godox X1T-N + TT350-N combo working!

Tags: off-camera-flash, wireless-flash, godox

Just bought a **Godox X1T-N + TT350-N** combo to work with my **Nikon D610** as an **off-camera flash** but X1T-N doesn't seem to be firing TT350-N at all. Is there any other setting I need to take care of to hook them up for first time?

**I have this settings on X1T-N:**

[image: X1T-N Settings]

**with this settings on TT350-N:**

[image: TT350-N Settings]

However, TT350 alone works fine as an off-camera flash under this settings without using X1T-N:

[image: TT350-N Slave 1]

[image: TT350-N Slave 2]

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: What is your camera's flash menu set to?

Comment: Flash menu on my Nikon D610 is set to: Bracketing/Flash → e3 Flash cntrl for built-in flash → CMD Commander mode → Built-in flash Mode: -- | Group A Mode: M Comp.: 1/1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My Godox flash won't fire off-camera. What should I check?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/106379/my-godox-flash-wont-fire-off-camera-what-should-i-check)

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the [Wireless ID number](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/112055/15871) on the transmitter is set to the same value as the Wireless ID number on the flash. If either of the Godex units is not capable of using Wireless ID numbers, then the ID number on the other unit must be set to "Off".

[image]

From comments made by the OP of both this question and the one referenced below to an answer to [Godox TT350n/Nikon D610 - How to fire my Godox flash “only” as a rear curtain sync?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/117942/15871)

> You are an absolute legend @MichaelC - No one on the internet talks about ID stuff. The ID on TT350-N was set to 1 (doesn't go below 1) and on X1T-N it was set to 0. I made both 1 and they're working now. :)

Comment: It is a pity that Godox does not prominently display the ID given how often that is the culprit.