# Godox x1r x1t and canon speedlite 430exii

Tags: canon, flash, hotshoe-flash, godox, canon-ex430ii

I was waiting for your kind reply on how to synchronise the godox x1r x1t & canon speedlite 430exii..
Thank you

Comment: What problems do you have? Have you followed the instructions in the user manual? http://www.godox.com/EN/InstructionManual/Godox_X1C_20170906.pdf

Comment: What have you tried that did not work?

Comment: Different transmitter, same system. Probably same issue. [How do I set up a Godox X2Tc to control a Canon Speedlite 430 EXII](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/112033/15871)

Answer (score 0):

When we have similar questions here, it's almost always the same thing.

I'm going out on a limb here and assume you have the transmitter properly attached to the camera's hot shoe with on-camera flash enabled in the camera's menu. As far as the camera is concerned, the X1T *is* the flash.

I'm also going to assume you have the 430EX II properly attached to the Godex receiver with the flash *not* set to slave mode. As far as the flash is concerned, the X1R *is* the camera.

We'll also assume both the X1T and X1R are both set to the same channel and group.

*What else could it be?*

In addition to *Group* and *Channel*, the newer Godox/Flashpoint transmitters and receivers (both internal and external) have the ability to designate an **ID number** of 1-99 (plus "Off"). The older pieces of the system do not have the ability to use ID numbers. In order to use the older pieces with the newer ones, the ID number setting needs to be "Off" on the newer units. Even with the newer units, the ID numbers that are set on each unit must match each other or the other unit will ignore it.

If your X1R-C uses firmware version 18 made since January 10, 2018 then the following instructions allow you to set the "RF ID" on the X1R-C:

> The customer can set RF ID. Operation: press the CH and GR button simultaneously and power it on to enter the RF ID setting interface. Short or long press the CH button to add the ID value while short or long press the GR button to decrease. Power off the flash trigger after 5s, and ID value can be set and saved. Then, power it on, and the ID value will affect RF reception.

To check what firmware version your X1R-C is running hold down the group button [GR] while turning the X1R-C on. The firmware version will be displayed as long as you hold down the [GR] button. When you release the [GR] button the firmware version will no longer be displayed and the channel and group number will be displayed.

There's a micro-USB port under the rubber flap on the left side of the X1R-C that will allow you to attach it to a computer to update the firmware using the [Godox G1 Firmware updater software](http://en.godox.com.cn/Downloads_s_Firmware.html).