# How do I set the ID on a Godox X1R receiver?

Tags: off-camera-flash, wireless-flash, godox

I've learned about Godox ID codes acting as a digital filter on top of the analog radio channels to stop someone else nearby on the same channel from firing my lights.  I know how to set an ID on my transmitter using a custom function. But the X1R doesn't have any custom functions. How do I set it? Can the X1R do ID codes?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can do ID codes. And how to turn it on was not updated in the user manual, so it's kind of hidden. It's in the revision history PDFs packaged with the firmware updates since this was a feature that was added via firmware.

First, hold down the **GR** button while turning on the X1R to see what firmware version is loaded. For ID codes the versions you need are:

- X1R-C: **v18** or later
- X1R-N: **v21** or later
- X1R-S: **v05** or later

If it's on an earlier version, update the firmware.

If your X1R can do ID codes, to set the ID:

1. Hold down the **GR** and **CH** buttons while turning on the unit.
2. Use the **CH** (up) and **GR** (down) buttons to set the ID value you want to use.
3. Wait 5 seconds. Then turn off the unit.

When you turn it back on, the ID is set.

Comment: Do you know if the current online manuals added this to their content?

Comment: @MichaelC checked before I wrote this. It's not in there. S'why I posted this. :)

Comment: When I wrote [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/112055/15871) to another question there used to be instructions, which I quoted in that answer, on Godox's site [here](http://www.godox.com/EN/Download.html), but that's a dead link now.

Comment: @MichaelC exactly. A lot of Godox website links are now dead, since they've rearranged their website (eyeroll). I'm switching some links to the http://en.godox.com.cn/ website instead which looks in better shape and more complete. Also the X1R instructions were *always* in the firmware downloads revhists, not the manual.