# Godox AD200 Pro will not fire with wireless trigger

Tags: godox, wireless

I have several Godox flashes, 2 AD400, and I've just added a third AD200 Pro.  I've setup the wireless channel to match the XPro, and ensured the selected AD200 group is active on the transmitter.  I've also checked to make sure all my firmware is up to date.

I tried triggering with 2 different XPro transmitters, and 3 different flashes as the transmitter, but to no avail.

I am able to activate "S1" and trigger optically, but would like to use the wireless for all the additional benefits.

Any thoughts, or do I have a dud?

Thanks
Paul

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My Godox flash won't fire off-camera. What should I check?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/106379/my-godox-flash-wont-fire-off-camera-what-should-i-check)

Comment: No, but thank you.

Comment: So all other flashes work, just the newly bought AD200 does not? If yes, you might check if there is a reset to factory settings and retry - otherwise, I would conclude, you have a dud.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the [Wireless ID number](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/112055/15871) on the transmitter is set to the same value as the Wireless ID number on the flash. If either of the Godex units is not capable of using Wireless ID numbers, then the ID number on the other unit must be set to "Off".

[image]

> The ID is already set to off on both the transmitter (XPro) and the unit (F7 on AD200 Pro). Just for giggles I tried them both on 1, still will not trigger.

Assuming everything is set to the correct Channel, Group, and ID Number: If neither XPro nor any of your other Godox flashes will trigger the AD200 Pro when the radio antenna symbol is showing in the upper left corner of the AD200 control panel, it sounds like the radio receiver may be defective. If it is not too late to exchange it for another sample from your retailer that's what I'd advise.

Comment: Michael, thanks for the reply.  The ID is already set to off on both the transmitter (XPro) and the unit (F7 on AD200 Pro).  Just for giggles I tried them both on 1, still will not trigger.

Comment: @Paulz I edited the answer to reflect the information in your comment.

Comment: That pretty much sums it up and was my initial conclusion as well.  I thought I'd put it out there in case someone else has had a similar experience with a solution I hadn't thought of myself.  I appreciate the input.