# How do I sync the Godox X2T trigger with a Godox V850 II speedlight?

Tags: off-camera-flash, wireless-triggers, godox

I am a newbie when it comes to using off-camera flash, I'm unable to sync my Godox V850II with a Godox X2T. Please I need a step by step guide.

Comment: Related: [My Godox flash won't fire off-camera. What should I check?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/106379)

Answer (score 1):

At a bare minimum, you need to make sure that:

- **Your transmitter matches your camera.** If you have a Canon camera, you need the Canon version of the X2T (the X2T-C). The Nikon (X2T-N) or Sony (X2T-S) version will not work on a Canon camera, and vice versa.
- **The 'Channel'** selected on the transmitter and the channel selected on the flash's radio receiver are the same.
- **The 'Group' setting** on the receiver matches one of the groups enabled on the transmitter. If the flash is set to "group B" and the transmitter has "Group B" turned off, nothing is going to happen with the flash when you press the shutter button.
- If the transmitter has a **'Wireless ID number'** set (the choices are 01-99 plus 'OFF' for no value), then the receiver must be set to the same value.

Wireless ID is covered on page 30 of the [*X2T-C Manual*](http://www.godox.com/EN/InstructionManual/Godox_X2TC_20190503.pdf)

[image]

If you have any older Godox "X" system flashes or receivers that do not have Wireless ID number capability, then the 'Wireless ID number' setting on the X2T transmitter should be set to "Off".