# Godox Trigger & Godox SK400 II studio flash

Tags: lighting, camera-basics, studio

I’m having trouble getting my Godox X2T (s) trigger to sync with my Godox SK 400 II light. Are these two compatible or do I need another trigger. Since they are both Godox I figured they would work together. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What group, channel, and ID are you trying to use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My Godox flash won't fire off-camera. What should I check?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/106379/my-godox-flash-wont-fire-off-camera-what-should-i-check)

Answer (score 1):

> I’m having trouble getting my Godox X2T (s) trigger to sync with my Godox SK 400 II light. Are these two compatible or do I need another trigger.

They're compatible.

> Since they are both Godox I figured they would work together.

That, actually doesn't work. :)  It mostly works. But Godox also does make some radio gear that's 433 MHz that isn't compatible with the 2.4 GHz gear, and one 2.4 GHz trigger (FC16) that's not compatible with the X system 2.4 GHz gear.  Just saying.

> What am I doing wrong?

Check:

- That they're both set to the same channel.
- That the group assigned to the SK400 II is active (turned on) on the X2T.
- That the SK400 II is in radio slave mode (hold down **<GR/CH>** and **<S1/S2>** buttons together at the same time; a little radio antenna icon should display on the LCD).
- That the X2T's C.Fn **ID** is turned off (the Godox AC-powered manual monolights can't do ID codes).

And if you're using the transmitter very close to the strobe, then also check the C.Fn **DIST** on the X2T is set to **0-30m**, not **1-100m**.

Other basic troubleshooting here:
[My Godox flash won't fire off-camera. What should I check?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/106379/my-godox-flash-wont-fire-off-camera-what-should-i-check)

Comment: Answered this [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Godox/comments/sb93hk/godox_400_sk_ii_question/), might as well dupe it here, since OP says it solved the issue. Doesn't say what the issue was, though.