# Why is my Godox V860 III-S showing a weird WL/circle symbol?

Tags: sony, wireless-flash, godox

I've put a V860 III-S on my Sony camera, but when I try to use it in transmitter mode, I'm getting this weird icon on the LCD:

[image: V860 III display showing a big WL with a slashed circle symbol]

What does this mean?

Answer (score 5):

It means you need to turn WL off on your camera to use the V860 III-S as an on-camera transmitter unit.

The WL setting is for Sony's own proprietary "smart" optical/radio system signalling. That's not Godox's system. Godox is basically hijacking the on-camera hotshoe communication and turning it into their own radio signalling.

It's counterintuitive, but with most 3rd-party radio flash gear, you have to turn off any wireless flash settings in the camera and have the transmitter on the hotshoe treated as if it were an on-camera speedlight.

The exception is if you shoot a Canon camera, since it's usually their proprietary wireless flash systems that's been reverse-engineered to create the 3rd party gear, and the 3rd-party gear can fake the communication the camera's expecting with its own-brand wireless flash gear.

IOW, on a non-Canon body, turn any wireless flash settings off. On a Canon body, you can use the in-body wireless flash settings.

See also: [My Godox flash won't fire off-camera. What should I check?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/106379/my-godox-flash-wont-fire-off-camera-what-should-i-check)

Comment: On the other end, If there's a receiver attached to the off-camera flash, the flash needs to be set as if it is on the camera's hot shoe, because the receiver is trying to fool the flash into thinking the receiver *is* the camera. If the flash is set to wireless, it will be ignoring the hot foot and listening (radio) or watching (optical) for a wireless signal.