# How do I interpret a Godox error code?

Tags: troubleshooting, error, godox

My Godox flash is giving me a cryptic error code on the LCD, but I can't figure out what it means. Is there a table or something that tells me how to interpret the error code?

Answer (score 2):

Not all the error codes are known, but in [the TT685 II-C manual](https://godox.com/static/upload/file/20220119/1642572923569086.pdf#page=26), I found [the following table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjjoO.png). With a little rewriting:

| Code on LCD | Description |
| --- | --- |
| E1 | A failure occurred with recycling the flash and it cannot fire. If restarting the flash doesn't clear the problem, it needs to be serviced |
| E2 | The flash has overheated. Wait at least 10 minutes for it to cool down. |
| E3 | The voltage across the bulb connectors is abnormally high. The flash needs to be serviced. |
| E9 | You loaded an incompatible firmware image for a different flash. You need to reload an image specifically meant for your device. |

For Sony users with the WL circle/slash error: see [Why is my Godox V860 III-S showing a weird WL/circle symbol?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/130635/why-is-my-godox-v860-iii-s-showing-a-weird-wl-circle-symbol)