# Will I get HSS with my Fuji camera and Godox flash gear?

Tags: off-camera-flash, fujifilm, high-speed-sync, godox

I'm trying to figure out if I can get HSS with my Fuji X-E3 and Godox flash gear, but my camera body doesn't appear on the much-repeated-about-the-interwebz compatibility charts:

[image: compatible camera models]
[image: feature support breakdown table]

Is there any easy way to tell if I can get HSS with either body with Godox's 2.4GHz gear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Fuji HSS

There's an easy way to tell if your Fuji camera does HSS.

Unlike all the other camera brands supported by the Godox X system, Fuji's HSS setting is controlled by the camera, not by the transmitters. **If you have a camera menu selection to set `AUTO FP(HSS)` on an [external shoe-mount flash's SYNC. setting](http://fujifilm-dsc.com/en/manual/x-t4/peripherals_and_options/external_flash_units/index.html#shoe_mount_flash), then you can do HSS.**  If you don't, you can't.

HSS was added as a feature to the Fuji X flash system in late 2016 with the arrival of the EF‑X500 speedlight. So, generally, only the higher-end bodies made in 2016 or later can perform it (with the exception of the X-T1, which can have its firmware updated to v5.0 or later to include this menu command). However, post-2016 production is no guarantee, as the lower-end 2018 models, the X‑T100 and X‑A5, both lack HSS support.

So, the other easy way to check is to go to [the Fuji website's flash X System compatibility chart](https://web.archive.org/web/20190328003928/http://www.fujifilm.com/support/digital_cameras/compatibility/flash/) and look at the EF-X500 column. If your camera model is footnoted with a 1, it cannot do HSS. If it's footnoted with a 2, it can, but with newer-than original firmware.  And if it's footnoted with a 3, it can do HSS.

At the time of this posting, the Fuji bodies that can do HSS with Godox gear are:

- GFX 50S
- GFX 50R
- X-Pro2
- X100F
- X-H1
- X-T1 (firmware updated to v5.0 or later)
- X-T2
- X-T3
- X-T20
- X-T30
- X-E3

See also:

- [the Fujifilm MILC template on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Fujifilm_MILC_cameras), which timelines the models,
- [EF-X500 compatibility list](https://fujifilm-x.com/en-us/products/accessories/shoe-mount-flash-ef-x500/).

### Godox HSS with Fuji

If the Godox gear you're using has built-in 2.4 GHz radio triggers and performs TTL, and is for Fuji you can have HSS with an HSS-capable Fuji body.

If the light is not for Fuji, then it must also have up-to-date firmware that can understand the Fuji signalling (see: [How do I tell if my Godox trigger or flash needs a firmware update?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/98899/how-do-i-tell-if-my-godox-trigger-or-flash-needs-a-firmware-update)).

If it's a non-F version of the TT350/V350, it may or may not work in TTL/HSS fully or partially, depending on which "flavor" it is. And the X1R receivers don't do cross-brand TTL/HSS at all.

And, with the following gear, there are additional caveats:

- AD180, AD360 (Mark I) + XTR16 receiver
- Mark I V850 and V860 + XTR16s receiver
- TT600 / TT600S
- V850 II

These lights/triggers will not do HSS with TTL or the XPro-F transmitter, only with the X1T-F or X2T-F transmitter with all groups in M:

- For an X1T-F:

  - The X1T-F must have its firmware at v3 or later.
  - **C.Fn-11** must be set to either **01** or **02** (reports vary on which one gets HSS to work with the XTR16/XTR16s). It must be set to **02** to work with the TT600/V850II.
- For an X2T-F:

  - C.Fn **SHUTTER** must be set to **LEAF** to work with the XTR16 and XTR16s.

With the XTR16 and XTR16s add-on receivers, HSS must also be set directly on the flash itself.