# Canon 80D hotshoe not firing triggers consistently

Tags: canon

I'm shooting with a practically new Canon 80D. Everything was going well and now my flashes are misfiring. I'm controlling my Flashpoint 600 with the trigger mounted on the hotshoe of the 80D. For some reason now it's not firing, when I hit the test button on the trigger it works everytime. I tried a different trigger from another light an the same thing. Every so often it does fire so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Get another camera and another flash borrowed, and combine the tests to see if it is the camera or the flash.

Comment: We need a lot more information regarding the shooting conditions and what exposure mode, metering mode, flash mode, etc. you are using to be able to provide any kind of answer. As it stands now it is totally unclear what you are asking because we don't know what your camera settings are.

Comment: "Flashpoint 600" do you mean an XPLOR/AD600 monolight? Or a TT600 speedlight? "the trigger": are you using a speedlight, XT16, XT32, X1T-C, XPro-C, or Flashpoint R2 Pro II? what versions of firmware are you using on the light and on the transmitter unit? How is the "600" slave mode set? (radio, optical, S1/S2?) Are both units on the same channel? [How close is the light to the transmitter](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/99294/how-do-i-get-my-godox-trigger-and-flash-to-work-close-to-each-other/99295#99295)?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/posts/102984/edit), to add new information (comments may be deleted).