# Godox TT685 N is not firing off camera

Tags: off-camera-flash, wireless-triggers, godox

I was using the TT685 with the XPro trigger but I cannot get it to work again.  It is set to Slave Mode and I have checked the Group and Channel, and the ID on the trigger is set to OFF.  I tried the trigger with the Godox V1 and it works fine.  What am I overlooking?

Comment: How far is the trigger and flash from each other? Make sure they are more than a foot or so.

Comment: @MarcWeintraub, if I set [close mode](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/99294), I can trigger with my Xpro touching my TT685.