# How can I update the firmware on my Godox gear on a Mac (OSX) or Linux computer?

Tags: linux, macintosh, firmware, godox, os-x

I want to update the firmware on my Godox devices, but I'm not on Windows, and [the G1/G2 applications](https://www.godox.com/firmware-launcher-installers/) from Godox, and the [F1/F2 applications](https://www.adorama.com/g/flashpoint-firmware-updates) from Flashpoint only run on Windows.  Is there a way to update the firmware on a Godox flash or trigger without having a Windows machine?

Comment: If it is not broken... why fix it? I am so ignorant on what would be a good reason to update the firmware on a flash on the first place?

Comment: @Rafael, if you haven't run into a bug then maybe there is no good reason. Some of us, however, have _required_ the bug fixes (or wanted the new features) that come with firmware updates. :) Personally, I wanted my TT685C to be useful in TTL/HSS from my -O and -F transmitters, and to gain the ID code feature as well as the ability to turn off the blinking red LED that indicates active radio slave mode. YMMV.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### OSX-only options

#### G3 / F3

Godox/Flashpoint has released an OSX version of the G3/F3 updater. However, as of 2023, it only supports updates for the following devices:

- AD100/200/300/400/1200 Pro
- V1
- TT350-P
- X2T
- XPro-P
- P2400
- TT685 II
- V860 III
- XPro II
- [anything newer]

For all other devices, or from Linux, however there are a few different ways you can do this, if you don't want to, say, purchase a cheap Windows tablet or haul that old Windows XP box you thought you'd retired out of storage.

### BootCamp / Dual Booting

If you're on OSX, you can install Windows on a [Bootcamp partition](https://support.apple.com/boot-camp), and run the G1/G2 or F1/F2 applications from there.  This has the disadvantages of actually still using Windows and requiring space for a full installation, but will have the advantages of speed, and no issues with USB hardware recognition.

If you're using a newer Mac that no longer uses an Intel processor, however, Bootcamp is not an option.

On Linux you could [set up a dual-boot system](https://opensource.com/article/18/5/dual-boot-linux) that can boot into either Windows or Linux.

### Command Line: dfu-util

If your device is the AD200 or later, and has a .dfu ([Device Firmware Upgrade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Device_Firmware_Upgrade)) update file that requires the Godox G2 updater, then you can use the open source [dfu-util](http://dfu-util.sourceforge.net/) on the command line to copy the .dfu file to the device, as [outlined by burning1rr on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/photography/comments/9t4xtl/heres_how_to_update_godox_products_on_a_mac/). The basic steps, according to that reddit post, after installing dfu-util are:

1. Connect the device with the appropriate USB cable, and run:
   `dfu-util -l`.
2. Check the value of the `alt=` flag in the output.
3. Run `dfu-util --alt <alt_value> --download <dfu_filename>` where *alt_value* is the value that was printed out in step 1, and *dfu_filename* is the path/name of the firmware update file.

dfu-util, however, cannot be used for updates that require the Godox G1 application, since those firmware updates are not [DFU compliant](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/DFU_1.1.pdf). It is also unknown if the G3 updates are DFU-compliant, as Godox is posting them as .bin files.

#### Virtual Machines

If you don't want to mess with Bootcamp or you're on a Linux box, a virtual machine has been known to work for Godox and Yongnuo firmware updates.  A full video tutorial can be found [here on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-ZU0_Tg2nU).

If you're feeling cheapskate and want to try doing this for free, you can use the open source [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and a [free 90-day Windows Developer's VMs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) from the Microsoft website. It should also work with Parallels or VMWare.

Comment: `This has the disadvantage of requiring a Windows license` - Actually, with Windows 10, you do not need a license to download/run Windows. Windows will block certain features until you enter one, but it is fully funcional without it - without time limits. And yes, this seems to be okay with Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

Often, without Windows, it's impossible to update firmware on devices that don't support operating systems other than Windows, unless some kind open-source developers take it upon themselves to support the products.

**Some options to consider:**

- **Use an old computer** that still runs Windows. This is what I did last time I needed to update firmware on my Godox flash.
- **Dual boot** (including Boot Camp). Takes up hard drive space, and requires taking main OS offline. Often doesn't work when needed. If Windows isn't used often, it may also freeze while attempting to download massive updates for itself.

  [A recent Windows update deleted user documents, pictures, and other personal files.](https://www.windowscentral.com/windows-10-october-2018-update-seems-be-deleting-users-data) Do you trust Windows to leave your main OS alone? What if it messes up the MBR and makes your main OS unbootable? What if wipes out your partition table so it can take over your hard drive?
- **Use Windows (to Go)** from a USB drive. VMs can also be run via the same USB install, so you can check that Windows is functional and updated before taking down your main system to run the update. This is what I use to install BIOS updates.
- **Use virtual machines** with USB-passthrough and other hardware interfaces. Often, the update fails before the flash attempt, but even if the attempt is successfully initiated, problems with the host OS could freeze or crash the VM mid-update. **You should consider using VMs to update firmware to be risky behavior that is likely to brick your devices.**

  Although different VMs vary in reliability, updating firmware is likely *not* a well-tested use case in any of them. You may successfully update several times, but if something goes wrong the *next* time, you may end up with an expensive paperweight. *I have bricked a phone this way.*
- **Use [`dfu-util`](http://dfu-util.sourceforge.net/)**, which [inkista describes](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/106263/75526). This program is available on some Linux distributions via the package manager. Next time there's an [update](http://www.godox.com/EN/Download.html), I intend to try this.

Comment: _You should consider using VMs to update firmware to be risky behavior that is likely to brick your devices._ I'm not sure I agree with "likely" to brick devices, but I definitely agree that the risk of bricking is increased. Personally, I have never bricked any devices when doing firmware upgrades via USB-passthrough to a Windows VM. But agreed, and to emphasize, the increased risk is definitely present.

Comment: That statement advises extreme caution – as if harm to equipment is likely, whether or not that is the case.  (should consider = behave as if)  While you haven't had problems *on Windows*, that doesn't mean *Linux* and *Mac* users will have the same degree of success.  It also doesn't mean that future failure cannot occur.  A device only has to be bricked once to be rendered useless.

Comment: Fair enough. To be specific, I didn't have a problem with Windows _guests_, running on Linux and Mac hosts. I haven't run on Windows hosts in a long long time.

Comment: I misunderstood Windows VM to mean a Windows host.