# How can I pair my Godox AD200 with my two Godox TT685s speed lights using a X2Ts godox trigger?

Tags: godox

I did my research and found out in order to get my TT685 flashes to work with my trigger I had to not only set the channel and group but also set them on an "ID" located in the menus.

They both worked fine, and I could fire both speed-lights.

**Here is my problem.** I went now to my Godox AD200 and there is no menu where I can change the "ID" and the only way I could fire all 3 lights (*two tt685 speed-lights and AD200*) is if i  put my AD200 on slave mode. I really would like to trigger all 3 lights through the remote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I did my research and found out in order to get my TT685 flashes to
> work with my trigger I had to not only set the channel and group but
> also set them on an "ID" located in the menus.

Actually, you don't need to set the C.Fn ID to anything; it just has to match on all your units. You can have this feature set to **OFF** on your transmitter/lights if one of your lights (say, a TT600) cannot use it. The ID feature is only to stop someone else in the same vicinity with Godox gear on the same channel from triggering your lights.  It's not a required setting like channel or group.

> ...  Here is my problem. I went now to my Godox AD200 and there is no menu
> where I can change the "ID"

[Check the firmware version](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/98899/how-do-i-tell-if-my-godox-trigger-or-flash-needs-a-firmware-update) on your AD200. The ID feature was only introduced with the arrival of the XPro transmitter unit into the Godox system. The AD200 was released before that, so, if you purchased it used or have owned it for a long time, it may not have been firmware-updated to include that feature.

On the AD200, firmware v2.1 added the C.Fn **ID** to its menus.

See also:

- [How do I troubleshoot my Godox firmware updating process?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/98901/how-do-i-troubleshoot-my-godox-firmware-updating-process)
- [How can I update the firmware on my Godox gear on a Mac (OSX) or Linux computer?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/106262/how-can-i-update-the-firmware-on-my-godox-gear-on-a-mac-osx-or-linux-computer)

Comment: thank you very much this seems like it might do the trick. i see that there is a firmwear V2.2 actually so ill try it out tomorrow hopefully I can get it  to work on my Imac.

Answer (score 1):

Set the ID to "OFF" on the transmitter and the TT685 flashes. For models without the ID capability to work with models that do, all of them need to have the ID set to "OFF".

[image]